# How do I play these tremolos?

Tags: learning, clarinet, tremolo

So for this piece *Lux Aurumque* by Eric Whitacre there's this thing called a tremolo in between the notes Bb and D.  What do I play during it, do I trill with C or something?

[image: Excerpt of score for clarinet showing multi-note tremolos.]

Comment: i added a picture that has a tremolo in it but the 2 notes on the sides are Bb and D

Comment: These are tremolos for clarinet? This web site says the first two and the fourth are not recommended because "*Moving back and forth at speed one will hear the failed connection*": https://heatherroche.net/2014/08/30/three-octave-tremolomoving-passages-chart-w-quarter-tones-for-bb-clarinet

Comment: Those tremolos are really bad for clarinet. If it's a band piece it would probably be better to play the separate notes divisi.

Comment: Ok I'll do that thank you

Answer (score 4):

Unlike trills and some other ornaments, tremolos (such as these multi-note tremolos) explicitly tell you what notes to play and what value they should take.

The fourth measure in the image is a tremolo between B♭ and D.  Combined, they should have the value of a minim (half note).  If you are interpreting the notation literally, each individual note should be a demisemiquaver (32nd note), i.e. something like this:

[image: As demisemiquavers: B-flat, D, B-flat, D, B-flat, D, B-flat, D, B-flat, D, B-flat, D, B-flat, D, B-flat, D,…]

But often, three-beam tremolos just mean that the individual note values should be as short as is practical.

---

Having said that, some of those particular tremolos are tricky.  The A♭–C and B♭–D tremolos are both *across the break*; the low notes are in the throat tones register and the high notes are in the clarino register.  This mean that you're being asked to rapidly change almost all of your fingers.  Various orchestration manuals warn that break-crossing tremolos are to be avoided, or at least scored with care.

Comment: Common practice (at least for music printed in the last 100-150 years) informally tells that tremolos should be theoretically played as fast as closely possible to the indication (except when used as a form of repetition of established rhythm). Still, ambiguous indications are quite common too: I've seen 2-line tremolos indicating "ad-libitum" cases (especially for percussion rolls) or 3-line ones for slower tempos that potentially allowed 32ths. When in doubt, unless an established practice is known for the piece/composer/era, the usual rule remains: ask the conductor/concertmaster/principal.

Comment: @musicamante Basically the rule is: if the tempo is slow enough to play the rhythm exactly you do it, if not then it's an unmeasured tremolo. In borderline cases like this one (very slow) composers should make it clear which way they want to go, either by adding or removing  beams or marking it "measured"/"unmeasured". But unfortunately they often don't.

Comment: The Ab-C tremolo is the easiest of those, it's possible to leave all the right hand fingers and the LH Ab key down.